# Regex returns digit string with leading "_"

Tags: r, regex, powerbi

Using R script in PowerBI Query Editor to find six digit numeric string in a description column and add this as a new column to the table.  It works EXCEPT where the number string is preceded by a "_" (underscore character)

```
# 'dataset' holds the input data for this script ##
library(stringr)

# assign regex to variable #
pattern <- "(?:^|\\D)(\\d{6})(?!\\d)"

# define function to use pattern ##
isNewSiteNum = function(x) substr(str_extract(x,pattern),1,6)

# output statement - within adds new column to dataset ##
output <- within(dataset,{NewSiteNum=isNewSiteNum(dataset$LineItemComment)})
```

number string can be at start, end or in the middle of the description text.  When the number string is preceded by underscore (_123456 for example) the regex returns the _12345 instead of 123456.  Not sure how to tell this to skip the underscore but still grab the six digits (and not break the cases where there is no leading underscore that currently work.)
regex101.com shows the full match as '_123456' and group.1 as '123456' but my result column has '_12345' For the case with a leading space the full match is ' 123456' yet my result column is correct.  I seem to be missing something since the full match gets 7 char and the desirec group 1 has 6.

Comment: How do you go if you just use `\\d{6}` as your pattern? I can't quite follow what the other groups either side of those achieve.

Comment: Can you give an example of a whole line with that _ and also two more other lines with or without _ then probably someone will give you a regexpr code that works.

Comment: feeding the R regexp string into the RStudio console I get the following:    > 
    writeLines("(?:^|\\D)(\\d{6})(?!\\d)") produced the string
    (?:^|\D)(\d{6})(?!\d)  this output looks like the pattern that worked in the VBA function

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with the str_extract which I could not get to work.  However, by using the str_match and selecting the group I get what I am looking for.

```
# 'dataset' holds input data
library(stringr)
pattern<-"(?:^|\\D)(\\d{6})(?!\\d)"
SiteNum = function(x) str_match(x, pattern)[,2]
output<-within(dataset,{R_SiteNum2=SiteNum(dataset$ReqComments)})
```

this does not pick up non-numeric initial characters.